# Share the issue with more than milestone

Tags: gitlab

Im working on the agile management system in GitLab.
For example i have issue X assigned to milestone #1, i couldn't finish it and would like to take it to the next milestone #2. In GitLab that's not possible to assign to multiple milestones. So I tried two scenarios :

1. Duplicate the issue and assign it to milestone 2
2. create a label that indicates that it belongs to the previous sprint What would you use? (it's weak because its gonna affect milestone #1 charts, completion percentage..etc)

Any suggestions?
How would you do it?

Comment: `In GitLab that's not possible` Are you sure? From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/milestones/#assign-a-milestone-to-an-issue-or-merge-request it states: `To assign or **unassign** a milestone:`.

Comment: Its possible to assign to the milestone, but not to a multiple.
i edited the question

Comment: Normally, you would remove the existing milestone and change it to the new milestone. Does that not work?

Comment: That will affect the closed milestone, in terms of the previous milestone  charts, completion percentage..etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues can only be assigned to one milestone at most at any given time. You mentioned a few ways to handle this, which should work as well.

The way I've seen this typically handled is that you would change the milestone if you miss the original milestone target. To keep track of the fact that the issue belonged to a previous milestone, you can add a label like `missed:old-milestone`.

This is how GitLab handles its own issues and milestones.

For example, [this GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369064) was originally targeted for `15.2` milestone, but wasn't completed in time so its milestone was changed to `15.3` and the `missed:15.2` label was added (both actions were taken automatically by a bot when the 15.2 milestone was closed).

This is a good practice, particularly when you use release versions or fixed-date milestones, because it becomes easy to see what issues *actually* make it into a particular release/milestone (important for communication/clarity). You can use the `missed` labels to figure out what work was planned for previous milestones but was missed.

As you pointed out, this will affect how metrics associated with your milestones are displayed. You may choose to snapshot your metrics before moving issues between milestones, if you want.

The approach you choose is a personal choice and the impact depends on exactly how you are using milestones.

Comment: It looks its the only way, i dont get it why Gitlab doesn't implement such a basic feature
Thank you sytech

Comment: @Zee FWIW, [iterations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/iterations/) may be what you want for tracking sprints as a potential alternative. Additional context and extensive discussion in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/5135).